# The environment variable JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation

Tags: java, environment-variables, filezilla

I want to edit my `.env` file of Laravel project with FileZilla but whenever I tried to open it I get this error:

**The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin) does not point to a valid JVM installation**

I had installed Java on my Windows days ago but I don't know why it shows this message when editing `.env` file of Laravel.

Here is my Environment Variables:

[image: capture]

Comment: Where did you read how to set this variable?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME shouldn't contains the sub folder `bin`!
For further infornmation, see: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/